# VBA Excel code to automatically format text (Credit Card Numbers) based on length of string?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

**Background:**

1. Number formatted cells in Excel have digits beyond the 15th changed
   to zeros ([*reason*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/269370/last-digits-are-changed-to-zeroes-when-you-type-long-numbers-in-cells)).  This behavior affects the recording 
   of credit card numbers which can be longer than 15 digits.  A work around to this behavior in Excel is to format cells that will contain credit card numbers (in advance of entering the data) as strings instead of numbers.
2. To display this string in a more user-friendly format I add a helper
   column that takes the string and chunks it out.
3. I do this by testing the length of the string and if it is 16
   characters I chunk it out as 4 4 4 4 (Canadian VISA/MC) and if it is 15 digits I chunk it out as 3 6 5 (Canadian Amex).

[image: Sample of my table]

[image: Formula I use to chunk in helper column]

**Question:**
Can you adapt my worksheet code for VBA to dynamically apply the desired format to the column containing my credit card strings whenever the data changes?

[image: My table after adding requested VBA code]

Comment: Yes it's possible to apply desire format to column or row using VBA! If your problem is only that you want to display 15 digits number which has been converted in Scientific Notation (by default) then Select data, go to Cell Format and apply `0`, Excel will convert Scientific Notation into 15 digit value ☺

Comment: I can suggest VBA code to convert Scientific Notation values into Number Format even without using your Formula,, confirm through comments will this works for you or not !!

Comment: We're not here to do your work.  Please share the VBa,  specifically the relevant section and explain why it isn't working. Give it a go, you may find you complete it...  Voting to close as this is too broad and off topic

Comment: Just curious - why do you want to do this? As someone who's done a LOT of VBA work, I typically suggest using worksheet functions over VBA whenever possible - it is far more resource efficient and typically makes distribution far safer/simpler.  There are some things VBA is needed for, but for something like this, the helper column approach is usually what I would recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will definitely need to have text format in your column `B`. Because otherwise Excel does it's stuff before this code, so the code cannot reliably do the work.

Then, you will have to open VBA window and open the module of the worksheet, which you want to update automatically. Inside this module paste this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim c As Range
  Dim rIntersect As Range
  On Error GoTo errH
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Set rIntersect = Intersect(Me.Range("Table1[Text]"), Target)
  If Not rIntersect Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In rIntersect
      If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
        If Len(c.Value) = 14 Then
          c.Value = Format(c.Value, "@@@ @@@@@@ @@@@@")
        ElseIf Len(c.Value) = 16 Then
          c.Value = Format(c.Value, "@@@@ @@@@ @@@@ @@@@")
        End If
      End If
    Next
  End If
errH:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

<sup>(Thanks, [@Ron](https://superuser.com/users/366681), for directing towards the `Format` function.)</sup>

Third, update the table name `Table1` in the code with your actual table name.

`Worksheet_Change` is the *event* which fires every time something changes in the worksheet. In this code, we first ensure that something changed exactly in the credit card number column, and only in this case we start checking the length and modifying values.

Comment: Take a look at the VBA `Format` function.  You can use it to format text patterns and output a text string, maybe easier than with the string manipulations.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - thanks a lot, it really simplifies things.

Comment: @ZygD, OP's basic problem is value more than 15 digits,,, which convert by Excel by default into Scientific Notation (Exponential),,, to convert into Number. Your code is not testing whether Cell  value is Scientific Notation or not ,, checking Length may pick Alphanumeric value too!!

Comment: @RajeshS - thanks, I have added `If IsNumeric(c.Value)` condition

Comment: @ZygD, it checks only numbers but never Cell has Value in Scientific Notation, it needs different VBA Syntax  !

Comment: @RajeshS - as the first step, I explicitly note that the format of the column must be text. In this case, scientific notation does not happen. If it does, it means the col format is not text, which means, the 16th digit of the credit card number is lost, which is the worst. No code will help then. The only way to prevent it is to make the col of a text format.

Comment: @ZygD, i think that you are not picking the crucial issue,, `1`, If `Cell Format is Text` ,, doesn't matters how longer the Length `14,, or 15 or 20`,  will looks like Number. But   the `2`. If `Cell Format` is either `General or Number or Accounting`,,, Excel Convert value into Scientific Notation `is more than 11 digits`. In this situation VBA code must check both Length as well as Scientific Notation ☺

Comment: @RajeshS, I dreally don't get it. First, In the answer, there is an instruction of 3 steps. If any of the steps is omitted, the user cannot expect reliable results. In other words, cell format cannot be General if the first step was performed. It is a prerequisite for the code to work reliably. Second, I really do not understand why scientific is any different from any numeric format. 16th+ digits are lost - this is the problem, it is not related to scientific format. I would ask for an example if you want to continue the discussion.

Comment: If I add a test for a scientific notation, it will not help. Because if the format auto-changed, the 16th+ digits were already lost. We must do something before that change, not after. And what we do is - change the format to text in order to completely prevent this problem.

Comment: @ZygD your code with @RonRosenfeld 's input (`code`Format`code` function) addresses the specific use case perfectly.

Comment: @RajeshS I specified in my question that I looking to format strings (text).

Comment: @CBRF23 performance is not a consideration.  Distribution is limited.  The benefit  is in readability and typographic error reduction.

Comment: @Dave Point taken.

Comment: @BlindSpots, Numeric data more than 11 digits like `111111111111` always turns into Scientific notation `1.11111+E11` but never to Zero. And this could be formated into Numbers as well as Text ,, but during that cell data must be technically  tested for `Length = 14` and is `Scientific notation` or not,, even though is Number  !!

Comment: @rajesh-s  The digits are formatted as Text.  Not Numbers. You lost sight of the problem: Excel conforms to the IEEE 764 specification & stores numbers to 15 digits of precision. Numbers requiring a precision of more than 16 digits cannot be stored as numbers.

Comment: @rajesh-s (continued) Exponential notation represents a number, doesn’t store it, and is not immune to the problem.  5583460004591596 entered into a cell formatted as Scientific or General will display in exponential notation as you point out (5.58346E+15) however it will also have changed the last digit from 6 to 0.  Therefore, there can be no Numbers to reformat, only Text strings that contain numbers.  “5.58346E+15” + 9 = “5.58346E+15”  in Excel-land but not in CreditCard-land. :-)